# is my code blocking node thread

Tags: node.js

I have some confusions over nodejs and would like some help. I have a table called camps, contacts and camp_contact. I have to show the contact list based on the camp the user belongs to. I used async to loop through the camps, which I save in the user session, and then grab the data from mysql.

```
        var array_myData = [];
    async.each(req.session.user.camps, function(camps, callback) {

        database.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
          // Use the connection

            connection.query('SELECT contacts.*, contact_camp.* '+
            ' FROM contacts JOIN contact_camp '+
            ' ON contact_camp.contact_id = contacts.id '+
            ' WHERE contact_camp.camp_id = ?',
                [camps.camp_id], function(err,data){

                if(err) {
                    //this will call the err function
                  callback('error');

                }
                else {
                    array_myData = array_myData.concat(data);
                    callback();

                }
                connection.release();
          });

        });
        //final function call.
    }, function(err){
        // if any error happened, this function fires.
        if( err ) {
          // All processing will now stop.

        } else {

          res.render('contacts',
                {
                  page
                });
        }
    });
```

The code works fine. Now the thing I'm wondering about is, does using array.concat block the thread? if so, how can I change that? I read around and according to what I understood, I/O operation that are not asynchronous blocks the thread like reading from file or database. Does having array like this `var array = ['a','b', 'c']` and looping through it would block the thread?

Lastly, is there a way to know if a code that I have written has blocked the thread or not? Because I get worried every time I write a function of my own.

I also get confused when a create a function with a callback like:

`function test(param, fn) { do something; fn(); }`

I'm not sure if this kind of function without a timer would block the thread or not.

Comment: everything blocks the thread (unless it's outside of javascript, such as waiting for a request to a 3rd party service/server to complete), what is important is *how long* it blocks the thread. so, yes, looping over an array will block the thread, how long it blocks the thread and whether it's harmful depends on how many items it is looping over and what is happening within the loop. the same with array.concat.

Comment: how many items, will vary depends on how many items the user will input over time. Is there a better way around it? I don't know how to use concat in async with my code.

Comment: Unless you're seeing a performance problem, what you are doing here is [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: How else would you combine two arrays? concat is specifically for this purpose, so using it makes sense. You could use a for loop, but it may be less performant depending on what the engine optimizes. and it would be more work/complex.

Comment: `.concat` isn't very resource intensive at all. Unless you're handling 10s of thousands of request per second, I wouldn't worry about (in which case, you would probably want to look into instantiating multiple servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if it helps you somehow:

> I read around and according to what I understood, I/O operation that are not asynchronous blocks the thread like reading from file or database.

In NodeJS the operations on file descriptors are asynchronous => non-blocking

The file descriptors would be:

- database operations,
- open/close files
- network operations

ex.:

```
fs.readFile('<pathToTheFile>', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
// if your file is very big, until it is read, maybe other requests will be finished
```

> Does having array like this var array = ['a','b', 'c'] and looping through it would block the thread?

Yes, it will block the thread, but operations like this are not resource intensive. NodeJs is an event-driven language (single-threaded), but also, in a multi threaded or multi process language, the kernel thread would still be blocked by such operations => the same thing ... this is maybe off topic.

```
// if you do something like this
while(true){
function test(param, fn) { do something; fn(); }
}
// you will see that you just blocked the thread
```

> I'm not sure if this kind of function without a timer would block the thread or not

normally you would put that function in a error handler, and it shouldn't block the thread if you're not doing an infinite while.

```
try{}catch(err){
// do something with the error
}
```